# What keywords should I use in Google Scholar for price search engine algorithms?

Tags: google-scholar

I am going to do a price search engine for my masters degree thesis. I have to search literature. My main language is not English, and I cannot find the correct query to search. I would appreciate your help with that.

What I am looking for are algorithms for classifiying products. The idea would be to finding matching products and assign them to a class, so I can sort the products by price, the way Google Shopping does.